# Sharepoint 2013 font - very hard to read / see

Tags: 2013

One big problem with Sharepoint 2013 is its font - very hard to read / see.  Have tried to changing fonts and themes. but nothing seems work.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details on what all you have trried.

Answer (score 0):

We have same issue when upgrading from SP2010 to SP2013.

And our solution is reuse 2010 CSS in 2013 version, by copy 2010 *forms.css* (`/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/forms.css`) and upload to a document library (or somewhere else in your site), then reference this .css file in a CEWP like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Resources/SP2010Style.css" />
```

It works pretty well. You can modify this .css file to match your themes.